# How to append data in existing row in vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have an array object like this:

```
0:{total_electricity_generated: 1567.7910000000002}
1:{total_electricity_generated: 1468.4869999999999}
2:{total_electricity_generated: 498.7319999999999}
3:{total_electricity_generated: 461.8369999999999}
```

Is there any way to append data in existing row In vuejs 2?

```
0:{total_electricity_generated: 1567.7910000000002, anotherValue: 1}
1:{total_electricity_generated: 1468.4869999999999, anotherValue: 2}
2:{total_electricity_generated: 498.7319999999999, anotherValue: 3}
3:{total_electricity_generated: 461.8369999999999, anotherValue: 4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
const vApp = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data: { 
        test: [{
             entry: 'first'
          }] 
   }
})

vApp.test[0].anotherValue = 1
```